# Adding views to RelativeLayout inside ListView yields repeated items

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I have a list view which uses a custom ArrayAdapter. The items of the ListView are RelativeLayouts. The "Light" views which are stored in "lightsOnThisTrack" list of a "Track" object are added afterward to its corresponding RelativeLayouts.

The thing is that if I add more items to the ListView, the views that were previously added to the relativeLayouts start to repeat on the newly added items. On the other hand, the TextView "trackText" is not being repeated, as can be seen in the example. As I've read on other posts, I know that it's a problem related to the way the ViewHolder pattern is implemented, but I cannot spot where the problem is.

[image: Example of the ListView]

```
public class TrackListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Track> {

    private static final String TAG = "TrackListAdapter";
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    public ArrayList<Track> trackArrayList;
    Context mContext;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    public TrackListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Track> trackArrayList) {
        super(context, 0, trackArrayList);

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.trackArrayList = trackArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (rowView == null) {

            rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.track_list_item, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
            viewHolder.trackText = new TextView(mContext);

            viewHolder.trackText.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            viewHolder.trackText.setX(100);
            viewHolder.trackText.setY(20);
            viewHolder.trackText.setTextSize(18);
            viewHolder.relativeLayout.addView(viewHolder.trackText);


            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {

            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

        }

        viewHolder.track = trackArrayList.get(position);

        if (viewHolder.track.getName() == null)
            viewHolder.trackText.setText(" NUMBER " + position);
        else
            viewHolder.trackText.setText(viewHolder.track.getName());


        for (int i = 0; i < viewHolder.track.getNumberOfLights(); i++) {

            Light light = viewHolder.track.lightsOnThisTrackList.get(i);

            if (light.getParent() != null) {
                if (!light.getParent().equals(viewHolder.relativeLayout)) {
                    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) light.getParent();
                    if (viewGroup != null) viewGroup.removeView(light);
                    viewHolder.relativeLayout.addView(light);
                }
            } else {
                viewHolder.relativeLayout.addView(light);
            }

        }
        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        return rowView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        Track track;
        TextView trackText;
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    }

    public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
        final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

        if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition) {
            return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
        } else {
            final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
            return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the ViewHolder. The problem is that you are not taking into account what happens when your view is recycled.

Suppose for position `0` you add two `Light`s to the `Relativelayout`. Then the user scrolls and the view gets recycled to another position (let's say position `10`). The `RelativeLayout` you are given already has two `Light`s in it before you do anything.

You either need to remove all the previous `Light`s first, or you need to be able to re-use ones that are there (and still you might have to remove some in case the row you're creating has fewer `Light`s than are already present).

The `TextView` is not repeated because you are not creating a `TextView` every time the view is recycled; you are only creating it when a new row is being inflated.

---

A few other suggestions:

- There should be no reason to call `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` and `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside of `getView()`.
- I discourage the use of holding lists of `View`s (in this case, `Light`s) in your data model. You don't have a clear separation between data and presentation, and I think it will only complicate your code. It would be easier to just store how many lights a Track needs and handle the actual `View`s separately.
- I would also try to avoid creating, adding, and removing `View`s inside of `getView()`. For instance, if you know there's a small, limited number of lights a Track can have (suppose it's five), then it's easy enough to have that many corresponding views in the row layout already and just toggle their visibility appropriately. Or, you can make a custom `View` that knows how to draw up to that number of lights and you just change the number inside of `getView()`.

Comment: Thanks, removing the previous views at RelativeLayout did the trick. Also, `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` and `notifyDataSetChanged()` turned out to be, as you envisioned, unnecessary inside getView(), just needed to place it in the code parts where I'm modifying the data set.

Comment: Lastly, I'm using these views inside the listView as I want to be able to scroll them without having to code the scrolling of the views. How would you propose then to do it? (I really cannot foresee the maximum number of `Light`s that will be on the `Track`, and they don't have an specific location on it, as the user can drag them along the track image)

Comment: @gotramaval I don't know what's best for your use case, but I think `ListView` is going to make your life very difficult if you plan on making those lights draggable. `ListView` is rather heavy handed about touch interaction control. If you can switch to using `RecyclerView` instead, that would be better.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it up, never worked with `RecyclerView` before, but it seems more flexible